# JSON expected EOF, got ','

Tags: json, csv

I was converting my JSON file into .csv and while converting there was such mistake as "expected EOF, got ','"

```
{
  "id": 22970,
  "type": "message",
  "date": "2018-11-24T21:08:21",
  "edited": "1970-01-01T03:00:00",
  "from": "lox",
  "from_id": 731504644,
  "text": "no"
 },
{
  "id": 22971,
  "type": "message",
  "date": "2018-11-24T21:08:32",
  "edited": "1970-01-01T03:00:00",
  "from": "Gox",
  "from_id": 417024817,
  "text": "ok"
 }
```

It shows that the comma after first block must be deleted,but when i delete it next { glows red. How could i format this so it will be normally converted?

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is incorrect with or without a comma.

I believe you are trying to have an array of objects with JSON. If so, the syntax should look like this

```
[ // Array of objects
    { // Object 1
      "id": 22970,
      "type": "message",
      "date": "2018-11-24T21:08:21",
      "edited": "1970-01-01T03:00:00",
      "from": "lox",
      "from_id": 731504644,
      "text": "no"
    }, // Comma separating array items
    { // Object 2
      "id": 22971,
      "type": "message",
      "date": "2018-11-24T21:08:32",
      "edited": "1970-01-01T03:00:00",
      "from": "Gox",
      "from_id": 417024817,
      "text": "ok"
    }
]
```

I recommend using any online [JSON parser](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) to check for syntax erros in the future.